# How to view RCurl options

Tags: r, rcurl

Is there a way to view the current settings of curl options in an R session?

My problem is that I am behind a proxy and have to set the proxy options for the connection to work, and after calling a listMarts() function (from biomaRt library, uses getURL()) the options are changed(reset?)  and the connection does not work when trying to call the function again. So I'd like to see the options before and after the function is called.

to set the options I use:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy="gateway:port",
                            proxyuserpwd="domain\\username:password",
                            proxyauth="ntlm"))
```

(I can see the setting of these options when I call options(), nevertheless they are not the settings I am interested I want the RCurl options)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but how about:

```
R> options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy="gateway:port", 
+                              proxyuserpwd="domain\\username:password", 
+                              proxyauth="ntlm"))
R> getOption("RCurlOptions")
$proxy
[1] "gateway:port"

$roxyuserpwd
[1] "domain\\username:password"

$proxyauth
[1] "ntlm"
```